# PoweShell, Set-Alias in Module

Tags: powershell, function, module, alias

I have a PowerShell module that contains only function definitions, and some `Set-Alias` commands to create some aliases to those defined functions.

Through some trial and error, I've discovered that if the Module is loaded, none of the aliases are active / work, until *after* I have run one of the functions explicitly / directly (i.e. only by the *explicit* function name as any alias defined in the Module does not function until after that) at least once, after which the aliases becomes active and usable.

Before the function is run explicitly, the aliases all show the following error:

```
The term 'xxxx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
```

My Module is running in PS 5.1. Is this expected behaviour, and if so, why would it be useful for the aliases not to be picked up when the Module loads? It means that I cannot rely upon aliases in any Module, so is there a better way to define aliases in a Module such that they will be loaded when the Module is loaded (and not later, after a function in the Module is run)?

Comment: since by default a module will only export functions, you need to make the aliases visible by exporting them explicitely like `Export-ModuleMember -Alias * -Function *` as the last line in the module

Comment: Amazing. This has had me scratching my head probably for about 3 years ... I had no idea about that restriction, and as the aliases worked *sometimes*, I was never quite sure what the reason was.

Comment: Just to update this ... it worked perfeclty in PS 5.1. However, I've now been using PS 7 a bit more lately, and it does not work at all in PS 7. i.e. if the Module is loaded, and I try to run an alias in that Module, an error is shown. Then, if I run a function in the module, that runs fine, after which all aliases in the Module *will* run. Any idea why it doesn't work in PS 7 ?

Comment: Well, no, no idea why really. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-7.3#-alias) the `Alias` parameter still exists and should do the same as in PS 5.1

Comment: I have to test on a completely seprate system, but consistently so far, on my main system and inside Windows Sandbox instances, I see this behaviour (works in PS 5.1 vs does not work in PS 7.x). Could it be a bug? 